# Failed to reach erlang port mapper - Couchbase error

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, couchbase

I am having problem adding servers to a cluster or create reference to remote cluster in **Couchbase**. I've created to EC2 Windows 2008 servers on Amazon in the same region and zone. I've installed Couchbase on each machine and the server is running fine. I've opened all the ports in the Security Groups just for testing.

When I try to add a server I get the following error in the 'Add Server' window:

> Attention - Failed to reach erlang port mapper. Timeout connecting to
>   "54.243.156.39" on port "4369". This could be due to an incorrect
>   host/port combination or a firewall in place between the servers.

I've used the same username and password on both. The connection problem happens even when I want to add a server to a current cluster when I first configure the server.

- I've installed the **couchbase 2.0 beta**
- the EC2 servers aren't in cluster, they are single EC2 machines

Any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have problems with Erlang port mapper daemon (epmd) (which allows node to node communication), because your  firewall block this port by default. You should open it manually. In firewall settings click allow program, then add port and in the  port number field enter the port number 4369/tcp.
And just in case check and configure your IP tables by netsh advfirewall command.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue adding a new node to a cluster. It could connect to the Erlang Port Mapper, but it said it could not resolve the IP address to the hostname. But it gave us the hostname in the error message for the IP address we entered, so surely it could resolve it.

Telnet proved we could connect to the port mapper on the remote box, and we cleared all iptables rules (with iptables -F) to ensure we weren't blocking ourselves.

The solution was rather odd. We had to manually add /etc/hosts entries for all of the hosts in the cluster, and this instantly allowed our new node to join the existing cluster. So something weird is happening deep in the DNS/Erlang foo, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, while adding new node to cluster.

As per the couchbase-server log erlang port mapper was trying to bind to ip (public cloud) which was not present in the system, but only private cloud ip was present.

So had to add the desired ip (private cloud ip) to the below file

```
vi /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/ip
xx.xxx.xx.x OR hostname
```